# Opencpu and Meteor

Tags: angularjs, r, meteor, restful-architecture, opencpu

I have seen [some](http://jsfiddle.net/ramnathv/uatjd/15/) [examples](http://bbroeksema.github.io/angular-ocpu/hello.html) of using opencpu together with angular, but no examples of using opencpu in meteor (where angular could be inplemented easily).

Is it as easy as just including `ocpu.seturl` and `jquery.min.js` in meteor (as is done [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ramnathv/uatjd/15/)), or does one need to think differently in meteor when using opencpu?

For example, [there might be some conflicts between angular and meteor](https://medium.com/all-about-meteorjs/the-wonderful-duo-using-meteor-and-angularjs-together-4d603a4651bf).

I know that is a diffuse question, but I've seen that I'm not the only one who does wonder about it.
Related:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/opencpu/rEi7lMK65GU
- https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-call-the-R-server-within-a-website-made-with-Meteor-run-some-R-code-then-display-its-output

For example (thanks to http://jsfiddle.net/ramnathv/uatjd/15/):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angular-meteor']); //added 'angular-meteor'

//set CORS to call "stocks" package on public server
ocpu.seturl("//public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/graphics/R")


myApp.factory('OpenCPU', function($http){
  return {
     Dist: function(dist){
       var url = "http://public.opencpu.org//ocpu/library/stats/R/" + dist + 
          "/json"
       return $http.post(url, {n: 100})
     }
  }
})

myApp.controller("HistCtrl", function($scope, $http, OpenCPU){    
    $scope.dist = 'rnorm'
    $scope.dists = ['rnorm', 'runif']
    $scope.color = 'blue'
    $scope.colors = ['blue', 'red', 'darkmagenta']
    $scope.breaks = 10
    $scope.submit = function(){
      var req = $("#plotdiv").rplot("hist", {
         x : $scope.data,
         col: $scope.color,
         breaks: Math.floor($scope.breaks),
         main: $scope.main
      });   
    }
    $scope.$watchCollection('[main, color, breaks, data]', function(x){
     $scope.submit()  
    })
    $scope.$watch('dist', function(newDist){
       OpenCPU.Dist(newDist).success(function(result){
         $scope.data = result  
       }) 
    })
})
```

Would the above be a "correct" starting point? How should one declare dependencies in `meteor` (i.e. opencpu, jquery.min.js) ? New to meteor so any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: Nice bounty, but please format the question to be more readable and add related code to it.

Comment: I've edited your post to make it more readable, I'll leave it up to you to come up with a question title that better represents your question

Comment: Thanks guys, I added the example I am thinking about.

Comment: When you ask if it would be a correct starting point, what do you mean? Does the code work? Does the code achieve all the functionalities you want? If not, then what is the exact issue? I have no knowledge of OpenCPU but I know that jQuery is included client-side on Meteor, and can be used in packages with `api.use('jquery')`. You may want to make your own OpenCPU Meteor package to use it.

Comment: @Kyll Basically I am looking for someone who might have a working example of `opencpu + meteor`. Thanks

Comment: As a working example of anything is an external resource, it is off-topic for StackOverflow as per the [help/on-topic]. Instead, try to integrate yourself these technologies and ask about a specific issue.

Comment: Maybe someone do have a working example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not using angular (not sure why one would need that), but here is a super basic setup in meteor:

HTML:

```html
<head>
  <title>opencpu</title>
  <script src="//cdn.opencpu.org/opencpu-0.4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Testing OpenCPU</h1>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
</template>
```

JS:

```js
if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Template.hello.onRendered(function() {
        // ocpu.seturl("//public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/graphics/R");
        // couldn't come up with a good example for this

        ocpu.seturl("//public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/stats/R")
        // this gives me a CORS error but the below still seems to work
        console.log(ocpu);

        var req1 = ocpu.call("rnorm", {n: 100}, function(session1){
            var req2 = ocpu.call("var", {x : session1}, function(session2){
                session2.getObject(function(data){
                    alert("Variance equals: " + data);
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

All I know about opencpu I've learned in the last 30 minutes -- little! So I don't know how to get past the CORS error. That error doesn't seem to happen when pointing at the graphics package, but for that one I couldn't think of a good example.

Comment: what does the `CORS` error say? Because I dont get any error:)

Comment: Is `Template.hello.onRendered` the only/best way to incorporate `opencpu` in Meteor?

Comment: It's not the best way, but definitely the easiest. The best way, in my opinion, would be to create a package from it as Kyll was suggesting, too. -- Glad to here you aren't getting a CORS error. I probably just did something wrong with opencpu itself.

Comment: Ok:) No I just used your ex!

Comment: what ever happened to the bounty?

Comment: Thanks. Seems like it may have been too late. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95039/what-happens-when-bounty-gets-expired

Comment: Sorry for that... Did not know that bounty disappears. I did not get it back anyway:P How would you do to create a package? As Kyll wrote "You may want to make your own OpenCPU Meteor package to use it".